# Wordpress SSL Remove mystery style loading have tried to deregister

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have an existing wordpress website that I have installed a ssl certificate on,
there is one style that seems to be loading that is stopping my site from being secure,

obviously it is showing as http so i know that needs to be https but i can find where it is located and where to change it?
i can see it in view page src

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery-style-css'  href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css?ver=4.2.10' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I have tried getting rid of it by adding various code to the functions.php file but nothing is working

```
function custom_dequeue() {
wp_dequeue_style('jquery-style-css');
wp_deregister_style('jquery-style-css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_dequeue', 99999 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_dequeue', 99999 );
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'custom_dequeue', 99999);
```

I am totally stuck, is there anything else i can try??

Comment: This might help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65523/how-do-i-dequeue-a-parent-themes-css-file

Comment: Thanks for that, but that is the same thing i have already tried